# Shortcut key for toggling Yosemite's Notification Center between "Today" and "Notifications" views

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts, notifications, osx-yosemite

Is there any way to use a shortcut key to toggle between the "Today" and "Notifications" views in Yosemite's Notification Center?

I have a shortcut key assigned to open up the Notification Center, but I often want to toggle between the 2 views, and would like to do it with a shortcut key.

It can be a built-in kind of shortcut, or even a third-party utility.

Answer (score 1):

Apple Script can do this thing and you can easily change the script and trigger it via keyboard shortcut 
Notifications:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "SystemUIServer"
    click menu bar item "Notification Center" of menu bar 2
end tell

tell application "System Events" to tell process "NotificationCenter"
    click radio button "Notifications" of radio group 1 of window "NotificationTableWindow"
end tell
```

Today:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "SystemUIServer"
    click menu bar item "Notification Center" of menu bar 2
end tell

tell application "System Events" to tell process "NotificationCenter"
    click radio button "Today" of radio group 1 of window "NotificationTableWindow"
end tell
```

Comment: Neither of your "Today" solutions work on Yosemite. Could you please post an update?