# Toggling Yosemite's Notification Center between “Today” and “Notifications” views (back and forth)

Tags: macos, mac, osx-yosemite, applescript, notifications

I want to create a keyboard shortcut/trackpad gesture to:
- display Yosemite's Notification Center first
- then toggle back and forth "Today" and "Notifications" panes every time the corresponding script is called

I found on the blog the 2 following applescripts to display "Today" and "Notifications" panes in Yosemite's Notification Center

Today:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "SystemUIServer"
    click menu bar item "Notification Center" of menu bar 2
end tell

tell application "System Events" to tell process "NotificationCenter"
    click radio button "Today" of radio group 1 of window "NotificationTableWindow"
end tell
```

Notifications:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "SystemUIServer"
    click menu bar item "Notification Center" of menu bar 2
end tell

tell application "System Events" to tell process "NotificationCenter"
    click radio button "Notifications" of radio group 1 of window "NotificationTableWindow"
end tell
```

So what I want to do is to somehow "merge" these 2 scripts the following way

```
If "Notification Center" is [hidden]
  Then 
    Display "Notification Center"
  Else
    If "Today" pane is displayed 
      then display "Notifications" (first script above)
      else display "Today" (second script)
  End If
end if
```

Almost succeed, but I tried different ways to "read" the value of radio group 1 of window "NotificationTableWindow" to define which pane is currently displayed, but nothing worked

Thanks for your support

Comment: I think this is related to my question (http://superuser.com/questions/860525/), which is still an open question.  I'd love to know the answer to these questions!

Comment: Hi Jimtut, 

I found your question. I added mine as comment, but it was deleted (maybe an offense to some policy). 
For sure, i'll let you know if I get an answer